# how can i pass event and parameter onHandle change

Tags: reactjs

```
const onCheckedValue = (notification, event) => {
  console.log('notification', notification);
  console.log('event', event);
};
```

// I want to pass the event and another parameter to the above function how can I achieve that?

```
<Checkbox
  checked={notification.is_selected}
  onChange={onCheckedValue(notification, event)}
  value={notification}
/>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an anonymous function:

```
<Checkbox onChange={(event)=>onCheckedValue(notification, event)} />
```

Your version doesn't work because you call the function `onCheckedValue` during render, which means that the you're setting the return value of `oncheckedValue` to the prop `onChange` instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are do that by wrapping the current `onCheckedValue` function call with a call back function and pass the values to the function from the state.

Get the values and feed them to this function

`onChange={() => onCheckedValue(notification,event)}`